# (Mongoose) When isModified is false?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have something like that

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  console.log(this.isModified());

  next();
});
```

The output is always `true`, reading the documentation it says:

> Returns true if this document was modified, else false.

I can't find a case when the function returns `false`.

**UPDATE**

This is the way I call the `save` function

```
let user = new User;

  user.email =  req.body.email;
  user.displayName =  req.body.displayName;
  user.avatar =  req.body.avatar;
  user.password =  req.body.password;

  user.save((err, userStored) => {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send({Message: `Error. ${err}`});

    res.status(200).send({product: userStored});
  })
```

Comment: Show me function when you try save User

Comment: Thanks@Artur, I just updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible because you are always modifying that data. If you want to check that **(isModified === false)** then try to update document with previous value(same value as before). You will get a false in nModified.

Like,

```
let updatedata = {
        'nOtp': nOtp
    };
    Model.update({_id: 'your_id'}, { $set: updatedata }, (error, doc) => {
        if (error) return res.status(500).json(error);
        // **Here below line you can check. If values is same as before**
        if (doc.nModified === 0) return res.status(417).jsonp({message: 'document is not modified'});
        return res.status(200).json({message: 'success'});
    });
```

You can do it same in your method

Comment: Do you mean that is  NOT possible because I am always modifying the data?  If so, that means we only should use the isModified() method when uptading, right?

Comment: yes exactly, when you modified something at that time you will get nModified = true otherwise false.